# LightTable and matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, lighttable

While there are a few things that are still being worked out, I am a big fan of the [LightTable](http://lighttable.com/) editor.  The [IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) is a remarkable delivery system, but managing a larger product is a bit easier in a more conventional development environment.

One thing that I have not yet figured out, however, is complicated plotting in LightTable.  With no cell equivalent, I am not sure how to modify plot components because each command seems to be considered independently.  In particular, I am not clear on how to work with subplots.  I am unable to connect the actual plot to the subplot array.  For example, consider the following:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(2)
ax[0].hist(np.random.uniform(size=100))
ax[1].hist(np.random.normal(size=100))
```

When I create the subplots, they show up empty inline.  The remaining code, however, does not cause them to update inline.  In the Notebook, all the code is considered jointly in batch.  LightTable interactivity is a bit closer to dealing with an interpreter in interactive mode (even though the script is obviously preserved).  I have experiemented with turning interactivity on and off via `plt.ioff()`, but to no avail.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated...